# When exactly are redux-form Fields marked as touched

Tags: redux-form

I have a login form that has both `touchOnBlur` and `touchOnChange` set to `false`. In basic user flows, the Fields are all getting marked as touched when the user clicks the login button. That's great.

In more complex user flows, like when the user opens the forgot password modal and then closes it, Fields no longer get marked as touched. This is causing my validation errors to be hidden (because we check for `meta.touched` before drawing errors).

So I'd like to know exactly what sets `touched` to true on my Fields when the form is submitted.

I'm using version 7.2.1.